# Choosing a @Produces method for CDI when more than one are available

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, jbpm

Basically, I need a way to disable one (framework supplied) `@Produces` method in favour of using my own `@Produces` method.

More specifically, I'm working with jBPM 6 and attempting to get it working correctly inside a container. The `HumanTaskServiceProducer` uses the drool's `EnvironmentFactory`, which always generates a new `Environment`. The code for caching the `Environment` in that `EnvironmentFactory` is commented out for some reason.

This means that jBPM picks up the JTA transaction manager rather than the Container transaction manager. I'm trying to supply my own producer for the task service that correctly sets the environment instead of using the default one.

Does anyone know of a way to specify a producer to use? In hope I tried specifying it as an `@Alternative`, but that doesn't seem to have worked. Either that, or a way to specify the environment on the `HumanTaskServiceProducer`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use CDI 1.0, alternatives don't work across different bean archives.

Otherwise (in CDI 1.1+) be careful to activate your alternative as specified [here](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#declaring_selected_alternatives).

The best solution for you is probably to *specialize* your producer. You'll have to:

- inherit the class containing the original producer method,
- override the producer method and
- annotated it with `@Specializes`.

You'll find all the info on producer specialization in [the spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#specialize_producer_method).

If you can't use specialization, your last solution is to create a *portable extension* that exclude the class containing the original producer from bean discovery (create a observer on [`ProcessAnnotatedType` event](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#pat) and call the `veto()` method on the event) so your producer will not be in conflict with the original one.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. I went with specializing the producer, thanks.